# How can I open Nintex Forms .xml files in Nintex Forms Designer?

Tags: xml, forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, nintex-workflow

I have different Nintex Form .xml files that I got from SharePoint Designer and I tried to import them to Nintex Form Designer, but I get an error stating that "An unexpected error has occured."

I could open the .xml files in Visual Studio, but I want to see how they look like on Nintex Forms.

On the Internet I only found the "Import" function, but that one didn't work for me. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly did you get the .xml files? They wouldn't be from SharePoint Designer. They should've been exported directly from the Nintex Form Designer. If you exported them from the SharePoint Designer, that could be the issue.

Also, are you sure they were exported from the same version of SharePoint that you're trying to upload them into? That could also be the issue if they're not.